# Congruence modulo a composite number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $p>q$, Why is the congruence 
$$(-q^{p-1}+p^{q-1}-1)a \equiv p^{q-1} \pmod{pq}$$ 
where $a$ is some integer, considered false? I can't see which gcds I have to compare for this statement to be false. Any help?

Comment: Right looking for certain values of p and q will quickly disprove the statement. There exists no integer a such that $4a \equiv (mod \  6)$. I want to see a more generalized proof where gcds are involved

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $p^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ and therefore the given congruence implies
$$0\equiv (-q^{p-1}+p^{q-1}-1)a \equiv p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$$
which does not hold.

Comment: From Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $p^q \equiv p (mod \ pq)$. May I ask why is it suddenly congruent to zero? I am quite confused.

Comment: $A\equiv B \pmod{pq}$ means that $A-B=kpq$ for some integer $k$ and therefore $A-B$ is divisible by $Q$, that is $A\equiv B \pmod{q}$.

Comment: Ok I get it $q$ divides $-q^{p-1}+p^{q-1}-1$. This congruence alone is a contradiction. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @hyunst Exactly. Any further doubt?

Comment: No. I understand it very well now. Thanks again.